# Find/Replace using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have a piece of generated text on Notepad++ that I would like to make some find/replace with Regex...

The text originally is like this:

```
private static final int ClientCode(removingQuotes(fields[4]));
private static final int InvoiceDate(removingQuotes(fields[5]));
private static final int IssueDate(removingQuotes(fields[6]));
...
```

I want to change the `(removingQuotes(fields[6]))` of each line and replacing to `= n` - where n is the number inside square brackets.

In the end, the result would be like this:

```
private static final int SeqNum = 2;
private static final int CarSegNum = 3;
```

I already have a regular expression that matches `(removingQuotes(fields[6]))`. The regex I have is below:

```
\(removingQuotes\(fields\[\d+\]\)\)
```

However, I don't know what to place in the *Replace with:* field, in order to get the number from the previous string and keep it. Today I need to change the number for each occurrence - and I have thousands of lines to do it.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could also simply search and replace `(removingQuotes(fields[` with ` = ` and replace `]))` with `[null]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly change your expression to:
`\(removingQuotes\(fields\[(\d+) \]\)\)`
This way you create a capturing group which you can refer to later.

And replace to:
`= $1`